# What is the exact nuance of 'a bit' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Would that I’d begun a bit sooner, but one always assumes one will
>   have more time

If you see only this sentence, what feeling does 'a bit' give? Can I interpret it the speaker hopes she didn't start too early?

Comment: The speaker hoped he had started “a bit” earlier.

Comment: She _wishes_ she had started earlier. Quite the reverse of 'hoping it wasn't too early'.

Comment: a bit is imprecise and depending on context. "I wish I was married a bit younger" might mean I am sad I didn't get married perhaps six months to two years earlier. "The runner was a bit late in getting out of the starting blocks" - in this case the suggestion is that the runner was slower than normal or slower than other runners by a fraction of a second.

Comment: A hair more than a tad, or maybe not quite as much.

Comment: Then, can I understand that the speaker hoped she had started earlier, even though people always assume they will have more time?

Comment: You _hope_ for something in the future. When speaking of a past event , it's _wish_. She wishes she had started the task a little earlier, presumably because time is running out. People often assume that they will have plenty of time to complete a task.